# Spark SQL performance too slow if the number of rows are 100000

Tags: performance, csv, apache-spark, rows

I'm testing Spark performance with very many rows table.
What I did is very simple.
Prepare csv file which has many rows and only 2 data records.
eg, csv file is like as follows:

```
col000001,col000002,,,,,,,col100000
dtA000001,dtA000002,,,,,,,,dtA100000
dtB000001,dtB000002,,,,,,,,dtB100000

dfdata100000 = sqlContext.read.csv('../datasets/100000c.csv', header='true')
dfdata100000.registerTempTable("tbl100000")
result = sqlContext.sql("select col000001,ol100000 from tbl100000")
```

Then get 1 row by show(1)

```
%%time
result.show(1)
```

File sizes are as follows(very small).
File name shows the number of rows:

```
$ du -m *c.csv
3   100000c.csv
1   10000c.csv
1   1000c.csv
1   100c.csv
1   20479c.csv
2   40000c.csv
2   60000c.csv
3   80000c.csv
```

Results are like as follows:

[image]

As you can see, the execution time is exponentially increase.

Example result:

```
+---------+---------+
|col000001|col100000|
+---------+---------+
|dtA000001|dtA100000|
+---------+---------+
only showing top 1 row

CPU times: user 218 ms, sys: 509 ms, total: 727 ms
Wall time: 53min 22s
```

Question1: Is it an acceptable result? Why is the execution time exponentially increase?

Question2: Is there any other method to do faster?